# segfault when freeing a pointer during string reversing in C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *str = argv[1];
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *dst = calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for(i=len-1; i>=0; i--){
        memcpy(dst, str+i, 1);
        dst++;
    }
    *(++dst) = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", dst);
    free(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

*Error checking omitted for more readability*
I don't understand why i got a segfault with this message: "glibc free(): invalid pointer:"
I'm trying to write a small program that reverse a string using pointers but:
1) the last printf print nothing;
2) i got a segfault

Comment: You're changing `dst`'s value.  You need to free the start of the buffer that you allocate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is you are changing the pointer in the calculations.
try use a `temp` or `original` for that like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *str = argv[1];
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *dst = calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));
    char *origDst = dst;
    int i;
    for(i=len-1; i>=0; i--){
        memcpy(dst, str+i, 1);
        dst++;
    }
    *(dst) = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", origDst);
    free(origDst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D i thought all the afternoon to it xD

Comment: I don't understand why an answer that suggests using `memcpy()` for copying one single byte is upvoted.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I wasn't `code reviewing` his code. I answered the specific question he was asking.

Answer (score 9):

You have:

```
   char *dst = calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));
   /* ... */
   *(++dst) = '\0';
   /* ... */
   free(dst);
```

You must `free` the pointer that was allocated by `malloc` / `calloc`. Here you modified it. Make a copy of it so you can `free` it after.

Comment: I feel that `*(++dst) = '\0';` could be `*dst = '\0';` because the pointer is already incremented inside the loop. otherwise there will be a double increment

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points to be considered. One, is to make a copy of the original pointer allocated by `calloc` as shared by ouah already. Another point is to eliminate the increment of the pointer when `NULL` is stored i.e. `*(++dst) = '\0';` should be `*dst = '\0';`. With these 2 changes, I am able to run your program without any issues.

Comment: Nice catch on the `*(++dst) = '\0';` (+1)